# How to find boundary point using bfs algorithm

Tags: algorithm, breadth-first-search

I think of the 2D array as a coordinate and try to find a coordinate value with a value of 1.

So far, it's a very easy BFS problem, but what I want to do is look at the following picture.

[image]

While I'm looking for 1 or after I've found it all, I would like to know the coordinate values surrounding the boundary in the order of the arrow or the other direction.

What options do I need to add to get those information?

Below is the BFS code that I use now. I can get coordinate values from the BFS function as shown in the second picture.

```
class Node
{
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Node(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
};

private int[] dx = new int[8] { -1, 0, 1, 0, 1, -1, -1, 1 };
private int[] dy = new int[8] { 0, -1, 0, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1 };

private Queue<Node> q = new Queue<Node>();

bool[,] visit = new bool[15, 15];
int[,] coordinates = new int[15, 15] {  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                                { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                                { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                                { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                                { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                                { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
                                                { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
                                                { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
                                                { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
                                                { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                                { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                                { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                                { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                                { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                                { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }};



void BFS(int[,] pixel, int x, int y)
{
    q.Enqueue(new Node(x, y));
    visit[x, y] = true;

    while (q.Count != 0)
    {
        Node cur = q.Dequeue();

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            int r = cur.x + dx[i];
            int c = cur.y + dy[i];

            if (r >= 0 && c >= 0 && r < 15 && c < 15)
            {
                if (!visit[r, c] && pixel[r, c] == 1)
                {
                    q.Enqueue(new Node(r, c));

                    visit[r, c] = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void main()
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 15; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++)
        {
            if (!visit[x, y] && coordinates[x, y] == 1)
            {
                BFS(coordinates, x, y);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you can check if the adjacent node to current node is 0, if it is, add the current node to the list of edge nodes. Btw, why not to use @BishalGautam's approach ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

we do not need BFS for finding boundary '`1`' values. We can simply loop over 2D grid and then for each '`1`', we can just check whether all of it's 4 adjacent `(i.e up, down, left, right)` values are '`1`' or not. If at least one of them is not '`1`', then it is a boundary point. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> find a coordinate value with a value of 1

Start by pre-processing the matrix
- Search all 1 values (this can also be done recursively) 
- If 1 value does not have a 0 neighbor, it means it it not on edge - change it to 0.
After the pre-processing you are left with only the edge 1 values, and all others are 0.

> I would like to know the coordinate values surrounding the boundary in
>   the order of the arrow or the other direction

To find out if the edge forms a closed loop, and get the nodes in the right order
apply BFS to the pre-processed matrix.
Seek a path from a node of your choice, back to the same node(a loop).